Hide unused panes in TeXstudio 4.8.0 side panel on macOS
I updated my TeXstudio for macOS to version 4.8.0 today, and then it started to show many panes in the side panel on the left (Asymptote Commands, XY Commands, Macros, TikZ Commands, etc.). I don't need most of the panes. I only want the side panel to show the Symbols, TOC, and Structure panes.
So far I have only been able to "collect" all the other panes together by dragging them on top of one another, but the collected panes still take up a lot of space—more than half the height of the side panel.
Is there a way to completely hide or remove the unused panes from the side panel (while keeping the panes I want to use) in TeXstudio 4.8.0 on macOS?


I'm haivng the exact same issue. It's really unfortunate that this version is a steps backwards in terms of usability for mac users.

You can minimize the sidebar as it was by default in previous versions by going to the Menu bar and clicking View/Show/Side Panel. I had to click it twice. I don't know how to make it go away entirely.

Hiding the side panel will conceal all panes inside. The original poster still wants to keep visible certain panes they use.

In the menu bar, go to View > Show. Uncheck the panes which are not relevant to you.
